# How to set cutomTabBar to rootViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I m using the library NMBottomTabBarController. (For ref. https://github.com/priankaliz/NMBottomTabBarController)

In AppDelegate.h I've declared property for **tabBarController**.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NMBottomTabBarController *customTabBarController;
```

In AppDelegate.m under **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
customTabBarController = (NMBottomTabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
customTabBarController.controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController2,viewController3,viewController4 nil];
customTabBarController.delegate = self; HomeViewController *controller = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window setRootViewController:controller];
```

I've `tableView` in HomeVC. When the row under table is clicked I want customTabBarController to be set as `rootViewController`. For that I've written

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDelegate.customTabBarController selectTabAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:appDelegate.customTabBarController.tabBarController];
}
```

This code is not working. I m not getting the tabBarCotroller screen.
What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with this line

```
[appDelegate.window setRootViewController:appDelegate.customTabBarController.tabBarController];
```

Try by changing it like this:

```
[appDelegate.window setRootViewController:appDelegate.customTabBarController];
```